# Obtener metodos publicos de una clase Java

Tags: java, reflection

Necesito obtener el listado de métodos públicos de una clase Java, pero no quiero obtener los `wait`, `toString`, `hasCode`, etc, que hereda dicha clase Java. Solamente quiero obtener los métodos públicos propios de esa clase, no los heredados de su superclase.

¿Hay algún método en la `reflection` de Java para conseguir solamente esos métodos?

Ahora mismo este es mi código:

```
 String miclase;
 Class<?> clase;
 clase = Class.forName(miclase);
 Method[] allMethods = clase.getMethods();
```

Y no quiero obtener los métodos `wait`, `wait`, `wait`, `equals`, `toString`, `hasCode`, `getClass`, `notify` y `notifyAll`

**UPDATE**
Este es mi codigo ahora tras usar la primera de las respuestas y ahora ya NO imprime los métodos heredados ni los métodos privados cuando leo los parámetros de los métodos:

```
String miclase; 
Class<?> clase; 
clase = Class.forName(miclase); 
Method[] allMethods = clase.getDeclaredMethods();
for (Method method : allMethods){
  if (Modifier.isPublic(method.getModifiers())) {
                    Parameter[] params = method.getParameters();
                    for (Parameter parametro : params) {
                        System.out.println("name: "+parametro.getName()+" type:" +parametro.getType());
                    }

                } }
```

Comment: No veo porque te imprimiria los metodos privados, como lo estas probando? porque en tu codigo imprimes los parametros de los metodos no los metodos

Comment: Cierto, no tenía bien actualizado el código e imprimía también antes (el código de aquí es un poco retocado). He actualizado el UPDATE corrigiendo lo que había puesto equivocadamente. Gracias por la ayuda!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Podrias usar `getDeclaredMethods()` que retorna todos los metodos de la clase, excluyendo los heredados. Pero no serian solo los public.

Para filtrar los public tendrias que usar `Modifier.isPublic(method.getModifiers())` para cada method del arreglo.

Ejemplo:

```
Method[] methods = TuClase.class.getDeclaredMethods();
    for(Method method : methods) {
        if (Modifier.isPublic(method.getModifiers())) {
            System.out.println(method.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

Ejemplo completo con ejecucion:

```
package prueba;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.lang.reflect.Modifier;
import java.lang.reflect.Parameter;

public class MiClase {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {

        String miclase = "prueba.MiClase";
        Class<?> clase;
        clase = Class.forName(miclase);
        Method[] allMethods = clase.getDeclaredMethods();
        for (Method method : allMethods) {
            if (Modifier.isPublic(method.getModifiers())) {
                Parameter[] params = method.getParameters();
                System.out.println("method: " + method.getName());
                for (Parameter parametro : params) {
                    System.out.println("param name: " + parametro.getName() + " type:" + parametro.getType());
                }

            }
        }

    }

    public void publico(int a, String b) {
    }

    private void privado(double c) {
    }
}
```

Resultado:

```
run:
method: publico
param name: arg0 type:int
param name: arg1 type:class java.lang.String
method: main
param name: arg0 type:class [Ljava.lang.String;
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: en la ejecucion del ejemplo completo no aparecen los privados

Comment: Cierto, gracias por su respuesta!!

Answer (score 9):

Puedes comprobar que el método esté declarado en la clase pertinente:

```
for (Method m: allMethods) {
    if (m.getDeclaringClass.equals(clase) && Modifier.isPublic(m.getModifiers())) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias también por tu respuesta!